# Looping through and Sorting Rows in pandas without using inbuilt function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

How can I loop through the rows and Identify in which semester John and Aaron had the highest grade?
***Note: Without using inbuilt pandas functions***

Below is the data frame I have:

```
  Index        Sem1        Sem2
  John         98           99
  Aaron        91           100
  Brian        100          93
```

The closest I could get to was to loop through the dataframe and access index in below fashion but I am unable to append those values to a list.
`python

```
    for i in dfff:
      names = []
      names.append(dfff[i].John)
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You should define the list variable out of the loop; otherwise, you lose its value in each iteration.

```
names = []
for i in dfff:
  names.append(dfff[i].John)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can identify the semster with the highest grade for each student like this:

```
df.set_index('Index').idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Index
John     Sem2
Aaron    Sem2
Brian    Sem1
dtype: object
```

---

```
hig = {}
df = df.set_index('Index')
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Sem1'] > row['Sem2']:
        hig[idx] = 'Sem1'
    elif row['Sem2'] > row['Sem1']:
        hig[idx] = 'Sem2'
    else:
        hig[idx] = 'Same'
        
print(hig)
```